Compiler Problems on Mac Sanoma 14; Cannot install R packages
I am trying to install R packages on my computer but keep receiving this problem:
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘dotCall64’

removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/dotCall64’

I have tried updating compiler from Clang to GCC, but this created more errors

Clang related. My issue these days "cmath" not find. On macOS 15.1, I tried to install some data.table extensions (Rcpp, ...). Maybe there will pop-up more reports in the upcoming days. No problems on Debian.
